# Why GraphQL child resolvers do not receive the obj/parent argument?

Tags: javascript, graphql

I wrote some resolvers following the default GraphQL [resolver function' signature](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/resolvers/#the-resolver-function-signature) that can optionally accept four positional arguments: `fieldName: (parent, args, context, info) => data;`. But the `parent` argument is completely absent in child resolvers:

```
...
const resolvers = [
    {
        Query: {
            prop1: (parent, args, context, info) => ({
                childProp1: (args, context, info) => 'Child Property 1',
                childProp2: (args, context, info) => 'Child Property 2',
            }),
        }
    }
]

const server = new ApolloServer(
    {
        typeDefs,
        resolvers,
    }
);
```

Unfortunately, I did not find any reference about child resolvers function' arguments in the GraphQL documentation. So I wonder how would be the right way to get the `parent` object in child resolvers.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvers that are methods of the object whose fields are accessed do not need a `parent` argument, they are called as *methods* with their `this` argument pointing to the object.

When you have

```
class Value {
    constructor(x) {
        this.property = x;
    }
    methodChild() {
        return this.property;
    }
}
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        prop1: (parent, args, context, info) => new Value('Child Property X'),
    },
    Value: {
        resolverChild: (parent, args, context, info) => parent.property;
    }
}
```

then you can declare a

```gql
type Value {
    property: String; # directly accessed as value property
    methodChild: String; # directly invoked as method
    resolverChild: String; # separately resolved
}
```

and all three fields will result in the same value.